# Could dark energy be the gravitational force of the perimeter mass expanding faster than speed of light?

Tags: space-expansion, gravitational-waves, dark-energy

Due to inflation in the beginning of the universe, there may be a perimeter mass which expanding faster than speed of light and gravity of inner space can not reach and pull it, but inner space can be pulled by gravity of perimeter mass since gravitational waves of perimeter space and inner space travel to each other and meet at some point. This gravitational pull by perimeter space may be the source of this dark energy.

I am not a professional physicist, so this idea may be fully stupid. If it is the case, i'd appreciate if somebody explained the reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He means a shell of mass around the universe pulling the inside towards it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Inside a shell of mass there is no gravity field. On top of that, if the universe is a closed structure, you can't position a massive shell around it.

Comment: thank you for the answer. are you sure that this perimeter mass acts as a shell of mass if it expands faster than speed of light? there would be no interaction between opposite sides.

Comment: @yılmazaydıncılar You don't mean a spherical shell? I thought you meant a mass behind every mass we perceive. Which seems like a shell to me. Or not?

Comment: yes i exactly meant that but since this shell expands faster than speed of light, i don't think it can not act as a closed shell.